# Can't align text next to image

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, and I can't get the text in the `header-loggedout` div to display centered within the borders. If I adjust the height, vertical margins, or padding of the div it always ends up moving the bottom border *down* for some reason. The image and text just won't align properly. How can I keep the text and image in (at least roughly) the same position but vertically align **both** to the middle between the top/bottom borders?

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2jgwqb0d/1)

```css
.header-lower {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.header-logo {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  vertical-align: inherit !important;
}
.header-logo a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}
.header-loggedout {
  font-size: 26px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-lower">
  <div class="header-logo">
    <a href="#">
      <img title="" alt="alt" src="http://placehold.it/310x39" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="header-loggedout">
    Test Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LaljiTadhani It's already there, directly above the code.

Comment: Does everything have to be in a div? This would probably be easier if you could just vertically align the image directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set display of `.header-loggedout` as `table-cell`:

```
.header-loggedout {
    font-size: 26px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0rho5L64/)

Answer (score 0):

replace this class

```
.header-lower {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: table;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an explanation of why your proposed CSS will work, rather than only giving the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning 
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2jgwqb0d/7/)

```
   .header-loggedout {
      font-size: 26px;
      position:absolute;
      top:50%;
      right: 20px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
   }
```